# findAll() is empty but findById is present

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Using SpringBatch, I would like to register errors in a table. At this point I am trying to write them in an h2 in memory database.

The following code is in a SkipListener @Service. errorRepository is @Autowired in the constructor.

```java
@Override
public void onSkipInProcess(Object item, Throwable t) {
    Error error = error(item, t);
    errorRepository.save(error);
    List<Error>     savedErrors = errorRepository.findAll();
    Optional<Error> savedError  = errorRepository.findById(1L);
    System.out.println("findById : " + (savedError.isPresent() ? savedError.get() : "NOT FOUND"));
    System.out.println("findAll  : " + (!savedErrors.isEmpty() ? savedErrors.get(0) : "NOT FOUND"));
}
```

Here is the model :

```java
@Data
@Table
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Error {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private long identifier;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE", nullable = false)
    private String message;

}
```

And here are the logs.

```
findById : Error(identifier=1, message=TEST WORKS !)
findAll  : NOT FOUND
```

Why does `findById()` find a result but `findAll()` returns an empty list ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your `save(error` as follows:

```
   errorRepository.saveAndFlush(error);
```